# Which should be considered as final coefficients of logistic model (original model or bootstrapped)

Tags: r, logistic, bootstrap, regression-coefficients, logit

I am new to bootstrapping. Let me explain my case, I ran logistic model (binomial) with 9 parameters. I divided complete dataset into train(70%) and test(30%). I checked stats for the model validity and then did bootstrapping over complete dataset. Now I have 3 sets of coefficients one from modeled train set, one from bootstrap original set (that ran on complete dataset) and last one bootstrapped coefficient. Now I am not sure which set of coefficients should I use while predicting in future? Below are all coefficient results where `prob_model$coefficient` is list fo coefficients from model trained on training set. In boot model result original is list of coefficient on complete data set and original + bias would give me list of bootstrapped coefficients. Now I am not sure which one should I use for future prediction. Please suggest.

```
Bootstrap Statistics :
          original        bias     std. error
t1*   0.9974316479  3.619136e-03 3.772206e-03
t2*  -0.0001680308  1.082013e-06 1.595247e-05
t3*  -0.0122041526 -2.240127e-05 6.932449e-05
t4*  -0.2103373656 -1.739921e-03 1.102777e-02
t5*  -0.0065004644 -2.184167e-05 1.525726e-04
t6*   0.2189768454 -1.910363e-03 1.564095e-02
t7*   0.0794606315 -5.810673e-04 1.066958e-03
t8*   0.0015241943  3.244818e-06 5.442563e-05
t9*   0.1165591650  7.599514e-04 5.028385e-03
t10*  0.0010037383  2.001973e-05 1.115370e-04



prob_model$coefficients
           (Intercept)                    a b       c                   d 
          0.9903145633          -0.0001745036          -0.0122231856          -0.2017792147          -0.0064298957 
            e       f            g       h       i 
          0.2032220963           0.0795136175           0.0015688575           0.1149821030           0.0011356770
```